# Why documentt.data.getValue() gives empty string?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Please help my to get a value from Firestore

I have a Firestore database  where "adminData" collection but only single value is essential. I will like to retrieve it from the firebase database and store it in string. I made a Data class Admin for getting values Can you please help me with the implementation in android studio using Kotlin?

```
 val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("adminData").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener { it ->
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    for (documentt in it.result!!) {
                        val users = documentt.toObject(Admin::class.java)
                         str2 = StringBuilder().apply {
                            append(users.payqiwi)
                        }.toString()
```

Why str2 is empty when return it?

[picture of debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjulE.png)

[picture of debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ERtS.png)

Comment: Please show how you are determining that the string is still empty.

Comment: I added another image for you

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Please have a look to my question

Comment: There is no way you can return `str2` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).